# PouchDB query keys using LIKE strings

Tags: pouchdb

I am encoding some data into the keys using hashes, and I would like to get a partial match within the key, something akin to `LIKE` in relational queries. Is there any API or trick to achieve this?

```js
const hashFirst = hashFn(first);
const key = `${hashFirst}-${hashFn(second)}`;
pouch.put({ _id: key, ...first, ...second });

await pouch.query('my_doc/my_query', {
    key: { $regex: `${hashFirst}-.*` } // doesn't seem to work like in find()
})
```

Comment: What's your index?

Comment: After some digging I believe I can encode the query in the index and use `$expr` in `find()`